# Как сделать фильтр цен по meta полям Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть записи в wordpress, в записях есть поля вида:

```
price_meta_key_1 == 1200
price_meta_key_2 == 1500
price_meta_key_3 == 2000
price_meta_key_...
```

В каждом поле указано числовое значение - цена.

Как сделать фильтр всех записей "`От ...₽ До ...₽`" по этим данным !?

В каждой записи имеется Meta Box "**Информация**" с дополнительными полями.

Как написать запрос **`WP_Query{}`** с фильтром по **сумме с НДС** ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Если необходимо найти записи, удовлетворяющие промежутку от..до, где хотя бы одно из полей информации с суммой НДС (металл, арматура и т.д.) удовлетворяют условию, то используем relation=>OR если же все поля должны подподать под условия от-до, то используем AND.

   ```
   $args = array(
       'posts_per_page' => -1, // выводим все посты
       'post_type' => 'product', // тип постов
       'meta_query' => array(
           'relation' => 'OR', // OR/AND в зависимости от логики
           array(
               'key' => 'price_meta_key_1', // сумма с НДС по которой ищем
               'value' => array(1000, 2500), // значение в промежутке от-до
               'type' => 'numeric',
               'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
           ),
           array(
               'key' => 'price_meta_key_2',
               'value' => array(1000, 2500),
               'type' => 'numeric',
               'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
           ),
           array(
               'key' => 'price_meta_key_3',
               'value' => array(1000, 2500),
               'type' => 'numeric',
               'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
           ),
       ),
   );
   $query = new WP_Query($args);
   ```
2. Решение из ответа с использованием REGEXP в meta query: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193791/use-regexp-in-wp-query-meta-query-key#answer-193841
3. Выбрать все мета-ключи с price_meta_key_, сформировать массивы и соединить в meta_query:

   ```
       global $wpdb;

       $results = $wpdb->get_results(
               "
           SELECT meta_key 
           FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta 
           WHERE meta_key 
           LIKE 'price_meta_key_%'
           ", ARRAY_A
       );

       $results = array_unique(array_map(function($v) {return $v['meta_key'];}, $results));

       foreach ($results as $value) {
           $myquery[] = array(
               'key' => $value,
               'value' => array(1000, 2500), // значение в промежутке от-до
               'type' => 'numeric',
               'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
           );
       } // формируем массив всех найденных ключей для квери

       $args = [
           'posts_per_page' => -1, // выводим все посты
           'post_type' => 'product', // тип постов
           'meta_query' => array_merge($myquery, array(
               'relation' => 'OR', // OR/AND в зависимости от логики
           )),
       ];
       $query = new WP_Query($args);
   ```

Comment: @Даниил так вроде решение с REGEXP должно работать - не пробовали?

Comment: @Даниил что - нет? Не работает или не пробовали? Какая документация нужна для ответа в SO с использованием REGEXP? Там полный код выложен.

Comment: @Pavel  Работает вариант с  REGEXP - "^location[0-9]" . Какой из предложных вариантов более оптимальнее?  По скорости и безопасности.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Влияет ли на скорость запроса количество "^location[0-9]" Например если будет [0-40] ?

Comment: @Даниил конечно, влияет количество. Только regexp будет никак не не [0-40], он не так формируется. Оба варианта предложенных - по ссылке и здесь в вопросе, в результате генерируют идентичный mysql-запрос (насколько мне видится из чтения кода). Так что по скорости и безопасности - одно и то же.